Re-exporting class in a namespace object loses its "type" in JSDoc
I have issue with VS Code, TypeScript (not used directly) and JSDoc where I re-export a class from a library through a namespace object to users code and type is not properly recognized in all uses:
path.js (class definition):
'use strict';

class Path {}

module.exports = Path;

paths.js (namespace):
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    'Path': require('./path')  // Re-export class
};

Actual user code:
'use strict';

const paths = require('./paths');

const p = new paths.Path();  // Works fine

/**
 * @param {paths.Path} path  <-- Error
 */
function drawPath(path) {

}

When using paths.Path as a type inside @type or @param I get TS error saying:

'paths.Path' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof paths.Path'? ts(2749)

I'm using regular JS code with JSDoc comments and have jsconfig.json file
How can I avoid this error so that a class in a namespace object could be used as a type in JSDoc comments?
